# Spark path style access with fs.s3a.path.style.access property is not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to write to an on-prem s3 bucket using `s3a` and therefore my spark `writeStream()` API uses path as `s3a://test-bucket/`. To make sure that spark understands this, I added `hadoop-aws-2.7.4.jar` and `aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar` in build.sbt and configured hadoop in code as follows -

```
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", ENDPOINT);
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", ACCESS_KEY);
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", SECRET_KEY);
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
```

And now I try to write data into my custom s3 endpoint as follows -

```
val dataStreamWriter: DataStreamWriter[Row] = PM25quality.select(
      dayofmonth(current_date()) as "day",
      month(current_date()) as "month",
      year(current_date()) as "year",
      column("time"),
      column("quality"),
      column("PM25"))
      .writeStream
      .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")
      .format("csv")
      .outputMode("append")
      .option("path",  "s3a://test-bucket/")

val streamingQuery: StreamingQuery = dataStreamWriter.start()
```

But it seems like this path-style access enabling is not working and it is still reading bucketname before URL as this -

```
20/05/01 15:39:02 INFO AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: test-bucket.s3-region0.cloudian.com
java.net.UnknownHostException: test-bucket.s3-region0.cloudian.com
```

Can someone let me know if I am missing anything here?

Comment: Looks like it is implemented in 2.8.0 onwards, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12963

Comment: Thanks @mazaneicha that worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tracked down this issue and thanks to [mazaneicha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/638764/mazaneicha) for the comment. This is done by setting hadoop-aws jar version to `2.8.0` in my build.sbt. Seems like a separate flag fs.s3a.path.style.access was introduced in Hadoop 2.8.0 as I found a JIRA ticket [HADOOP-12963](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12963) for this issue. And it worked.

Comment: better make sure that all hadoop.version artifacts are in perfect sync: mix-and-match is doomed

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue ,and it works with hadoop-aws: 3.2.0 version.
and with dependency, it works for me

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.375</version>         
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```