# NoClassDefFoundError raised when reading Minio data using PySpark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, minio

I've tried installing different versions of Spark and of the required jar files, but had no success. I'm using a Macbook Air M1.

### How to replicate

Run a Minio instance locally at port 9000.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/spark-py

COPY ./hadoop-aws-3.3.6.jar /opt/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-3.3.6.jar
COPY ./aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.367.jar /opt/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.367.jar

COPY . .
```

Then run:

```
docker run  --network="host" -it <image-name> /opt/spark/bin/pyspark
```

Paste the following Python code inside the container:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "minio")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "minio123" )
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://localhost:9000")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false")

df = spark.read.json('s3a://lake-test/data.json')
```

Receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 418, in json
    return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 169, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o45.json.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/impl/prefetch/PrefetchingStatistics
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:362)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.impl.prefetch.PrefetchingStatistics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
```

I've received similar errors before, but installing the correct jar files (see Dockerfile) seemed to solve it.

I've also tried doing everything above outside of a docker container, but got the exact same result. Same thing without using Python (though the Spark shell directly).

Comment: I had similar problems, and a working example with compatible version numbers is posted here if it helps anyone else: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77592717/458370

Answer (score 2):

#### Make sure the version of your Hadoop jars matches the base image

To find this run

```bash
docker run --rm -it apache/spark-py:latest bash -c 'find / -name "hadoop-client*.jar" 2> /dev/null'
```

As of this writing, `latest` is `v3.4.0` and the output of the above command is

```
<...verbose tini output...>
/opt/spark/jars/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar
/opt/spark/jars/hadoop-client-runtime-3.3.4.jar
```

Update your Docker image to use a matching `hadoop-aws` (e.g. `./hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar`).